# How to plot a filled contour, with z axis being a factor

Tags: r, graph, plot

I have a dataset

```
test<-data.frame(expand.grid(x=seq(0.01,1,0.01), y=seq(0.01,1,0.01)))
test$z<-c(rep(1,2500),rep(2,2500),rep(3,2500),rep(4,2500))
```

(x,y) define cartesian coordinates. I would like to plot a filled contour plot, with `xlim=ylim=c(0,1)`, and the color being z (a factor with 4 levels).

i could do :

`plot(test$x, test$y, col=test$z, pch=16)` but it does not look good.

The example looks terrible but in my data makes sense. I am familiar with `akima::interp` and `filled.contour()` but i do not wish any interpolation and z is not continuous but a factor.

Could you please recommend me a proper and pleasant visualization for my data? I would prefer base graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `image` for example :

```
image(outer(seq(0.01,1,0.01),seq(0.01,1,0.01),
            FUN=function(x,y)test$z))
```

[image]

I think you can use `raster` package to deal better with such plots.

Comment: This gives very different results that plot(test$x, test$y, col=test$z, pch=16). Must be wrong

Comment: @ECII My first example was just to propose `image` as solution.I update my answer to have the same levels order than your initial data.